# Deserialize option<'a>

Tags: serialization, f#, datacontract

When trying to deserialize a record member of type `Header option` returned from a JSON string, I get the following exception:

> The data contract type
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[[MyWeb.Controllers.Header,
>   MyWeb.Controllers, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot be deserialized because the required
>   data member 'value' was not found.

I'm serializing/deserializing a `Message` record:

```
[<DataContract>]
type Header = 
    { [<DataMember>] mutable ID          : int
      [<DataMember>] mutable Description : string }

[<DataContract>]
type Message =
    { [<DataMember>] mutable ID          : int
      [<DataMember>] mutable Header      : Header option
      [<DataMember>] mutable SenderID    : string
      [<DataMember>] mutable ReceiverID  : string }
```

The code I use to deserialize the JSON:

```
let deserializeJson<'a> (s:string) =   
    use ms = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes s)   
    let serialize = DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'a>)   
    serialize.ReadObject ms :?> 'a
```

And the actual raw JSON result:

```
"Message":
{
    "ID":13,
    "Header": { "Value":{"ID":21,"Description":"some"}},
    "SenderID":"312345332423",
    "ReceiverID":"16564543423" 
}
```

The question: how do I deserialize a `'a option`?

**Update**

ASP.NET MVC uses `JavaScriptSerializer` by default to serialize objects and I'm using `DataContractJsonSerializer` to deserialize.

For some reason it seems `DataContractJsonSerializer` can't read the JSON string unless the `Value` property for the option is in lowercase (as pointed out by @svick). A dirty fix would be to replace "Value" with "value" in the returned JSON string, but I've chosen to go with Roberts' suggestion.

Comment: How does the JSON string look like?

Comment: And how do you serialize it? The obvious way throws an exception for me. Also, I get the same exception (complaining that there are no set accessors) when running `deserializeJson`.

Comment: @svick, I'm using ASP.NET MVC for a REST API. The API is written in F#. I serialize the records using the `Json` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504936.aspx) method from the `Controller` class. To answer your former question, then the record members on the client side should be mutable in order to be set (see update).

Comment: Hmm, using different serializer on each side is probably the issue. If you change the JSON to have `value` (lowercase), then it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to hop over to using [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (a.k.a Newtonsoft.Json) instead of the json serializer that comes with the .NET framework, then you could use the [option serializer](https://github.com/robertpi/FsRavenDbTools/blob/master/src/FsRavenDbTools/Converters.fs) I built to allow me to work more effectively with ravendb. Should just be a matter of registering the convert with the serializer and calling Deserialize.